# How to find the expected value of a parametric function?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, parametric-functions

Suppose $a \ge 0$ is a parameter and $X_1$ is an uniform random variable in $[1,4]$ and $X_2$ is an uniform random variable in $[1/2,1]$. How to find the expected value of $\max\{5-X_1a, 3-X_2a,0\}$?

Comment: Do you mean a uniform random variables?

Comment: Yes. I updated my question

Answer (score 3):

If the random variables have Uniform distributions, then the following finds the mean:

```
dist = TransformedDistribution[Max[5 - x1 a, 3 - x2 a, 0], 
  {x1 \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{1, 4}], 
   x2 \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{1/2, 1}]}];
```

Mean[dist]

[image: Meatn of transformed random variable]